# how to create link in telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am designing a telegram bot. I want to show some links e.g.

> 1- wkpviana
>
> 2- vianahosting

that when user click it, open

```
http://wkpviana.net 
http://vianahosting.ir
```

in browser.
How I can create it in php?
part of my code is:

```
<?php
...
$sLink = "";
foreach($Links as $Row){
    $sLink .= "<a href='".$Row->link_url."'>".$Row->link_name."</a>";
}
$Text = $sLink;
...
$URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$Token."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$ChatID."&text=".$Text."&reply_markup=".json_encode($KB);
file_get_contents($URL);
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be attempting to send the links with the `<a>` tag, which works fine, but requires you to use the `parse_mode=html` parameter, as documented [here.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)

I believe it would look a bit like this:

```
$URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$Token."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$ChatID."&text=".$Text."&parse_mode=HTML&reply_markup=".json_encode($KB);
```